# Why is the value of my password field always an empty string?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I've been working on my javascript skills lately and the password validation has given me a lot of trouble. The last thing that is stopping me is that the password field always has a value of an empty string for some reason.

It always logs out an empty string, no matter what i put in the input field. I've tried a different browser but that did not have an effect.

```
<input type="password" id="password">
<button type="submit" onclick="submitIt()">
Submit
</button>
```

js

```
const passWord = document.getElementById('password').value

function submitIt() {
console.log(passWord)
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/k4owfLzn/3/

Comment: Because "const passWord = document.getElementById('password').value" sets a definite value (which is empty). At the time you click, the value does not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value is always empty because the value of passWord is set on the loading of page. It is not updated after a user types in a value.

If you modify the code so it is like this you should get the value.

```
function submitIt() {
  const passWord = document.getElementById('password').value;

  console.log('passWord: ', passWord)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That does work, and im incredibly sorry for not realising that.

Comment: @Ashhu I've made the mistake as well as many others time and time again. Sometimes you just need fresh eyes to look over something.

Answer (score 0):

> const passWord

was declared outside the function.
I am sure that if you insert it inside the function, you will have the result you were looking for.  :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).